# Use a single javascript file as either a module with exports or as a standalone script

Tags: javascript

We have use cases for both modules / node.js usages as well as standalone/vanilla javascript.  The `export` statement can not be used in some cases in the latter.

```
export class MyClass
```

Is there any syntax to be able to achieve the `export` needed for `modules` yet still be compatible with running the javascript file ad-hoc - e.g. from an IDE (in my case `PyCharm`? If I try to run the javascript file directly we see:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in JavaScript itself, no. A compilation unit either is or isn't a module, it can't be context-sensitive.¹

Bundlers like Rollup.js and Webpack have ways of doing it (by not using JavaScript's built-in module system), but there's no native way.

---

¹ Except that if it doesn't use `import` or `export`, it can be either a script or a module that doesn't export anything and doesn't statically import anything. (Scripts can use dynamic import.)

Comment: Not the result I was hoping for - but "don't shoot the messenger"